# Not able to capture a certain value while traversing through a JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have nested PHP Arrays decoded from a JSON String. I am trying to capture the value of the property "dealname" and save it to a variable. The Issue is I am not able to Iterate correctly over the array.

The Array appears to be in this format

> Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [portalId] => 62515
>   [dealId] => 291809941 [isDeleted] => [associations] => Array (
>   [associatedVids] => Array ( [0] => 6810424 ) [associatedCompanyIds] =>
>   Array ( ) [associatedDealIds] => Array ( ) ) [properties] => Array (
>   [dealname] => Array ( [value] => Leaky faucet in LA [timestamp] =>
>   1525454097337 [source] => API [sourceId] => [versions] => Array ( [0]
>   => Array ( [name] => dealname [value] => Leaky faucet in LA [timestamp] => 1525454097337 [source] => API [sourceVid] => Array ( )
>   ) ) ) [hs_lastmodifieddate] => Array ( [value] => 1525454103922
>   [timestamp] => 1525454103922 [source] => CALCULATED [sourceId] =>
>   [versions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => hs_lastmodifieddate
>   [value] => 1525454103922 [timestamp] => 1525454103922 [source] =

In this case, I would like to get the value of the dealName "Leaky faucet in LA" . I have written some code which does not achieve the purpose-

```
foreach($json as $key=>$value){
foreach ($json as $key2=>$value2){

foreach ($json as $key3=>$value3){
$name=$value['dealname'];

}}}
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

JSON String

> "results":[{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292208360,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6814776],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"dealname":{"value":"Leaky
>   faucet in
>   LA","timestamp":1525459053872,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Leaky
>   faucet in
>   LA","timestamp":1525459053872,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525459067507","timestamp":1525459067507,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525459067507","timestamp":1525459067507,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525459058085,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814776","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525459058085,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814776","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525459053872","timestamp":1525459053872,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525459053872","timestamp":1525459053872,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525459053872","timestamp":1525459053872,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525459053872","timestamp":1525459053872,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525459054272,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525459054272,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525459067425,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814776","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525459067425,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814776","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207735,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6814826],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Oba","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Oba","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458931861","timestamp":1525458931861,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458931861","timestamp":1525458931861,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458930020,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814826","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458930020,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814826","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458925035","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458925035","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458925035","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458925035","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458925466,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458925466,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458931575,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814826","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458931575,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814826","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458925035,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292315704,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6815024],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Linkbridge","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Linkbridge","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458934927","timestamp":1525458934927,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458934927","timestamp":1525458934927,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458930421,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6815024","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458930421,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6815024","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458923536","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458923536","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458923536","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458923536","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458923730,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458923730,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458934742,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6815024","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458934742,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6815024","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458923536,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207709,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6814974],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Flipbug","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Flipbug","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458928922","timestamp":1525458928922,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458928922","timestamp":1525458928922,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458924445,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814974","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458924445,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814974","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458922128","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458922128","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458922128","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458922128","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458922399,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458922399,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458928846,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814974","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458928846,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814974","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458922128,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207701,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6814379],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Minyx","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Minyx","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458923407","timestamp":1525458923407,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458923407","timestamp":1525458923407,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458923062,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814379","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458923062,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814379","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458920647","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458920647","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458920647","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458920647","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458920877,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458920877,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458923062,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814379","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458923062,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814379","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458920647,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207686,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6813932],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Trilith","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Trilith","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458926045","timestamp":1525458926045,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458926045","timestamp":1525458926045,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458920620,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6813932","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458920620,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6813932","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458918074","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458918074","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458918074","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458918074","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458918409,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458918409,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458925870,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6813932","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458925870,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6813932","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458918074,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207684,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6814825],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Oloo","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Oloo","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458922566","timestamp":1525458922566,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458922566","timestamp":1525458922566,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458920963,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814825","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458920963,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814825","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458916656","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458916656","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458916656","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458916656","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458916929,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458916929,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458922289,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814825","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458922289,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814825","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458916656,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207682,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6815024],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Voonyx","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Voonyx","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458935304","timestamp":1525458935304,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458935304","timestamp":1525458935304,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458920877,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814924","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458920877,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814924","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458915210","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458915210","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458915210","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458915210","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458915403,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458915403,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458934819,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6815024","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458934819,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6815024","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458915210,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292207680,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6814427],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Jazzy","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Jazzy","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458917833","timestamp":1525458917833,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458917833","timestamp":1525458917833,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458917576,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814427","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458917576,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814427","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458913722","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458913722","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458913722","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458913722","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458913873,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458913873,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_1":{"value":"API","timestamp":1525458917576,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814427","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_1","value":"API","timestamp":1525458917576,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6814427","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"newbusiness","timestamp":1525458913722,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"imports":[],"stateChanges":[]},{"portalId":62515,"dealId":292285876,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[6813931],"associatedCompanyIds":[],"associatedDealIds":[]},"properties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Vipe","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","value":"Vipe","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1525458919681","timestamp":1525458919681,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1525458919681","timestamp":1525458919681,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source":{"value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458916508,"source":"DEALS","sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6813931","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source","value":"OFFLINE","timestamp":1525458916508,"sourceId":"deal
>   sync triggered by
>   vid=6813931","source":"DEALS","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"1","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"1","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"appointmentscheduled","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1525458912293","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"1525458912293","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1525458912293","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1525458912293","timestamp":1525458912293,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_analytics_source_data_2":{"value":"","timestamp":1525458912496,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceId":"deal
>   sync with no associated
>   contacts","versions":[{"name":"hs_analytics_source_data_2","value":"","timestamp":1525458912496,"sourceId":"deal

URL: [PHPFiddle](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn//%20Get%20cURL%20resource%5Cn$curl%20=%20curl_init();%5Cn//%20Set%20some%20options%20-%20we%20are%20passing%20in%20a%20useragent%20too%20here%5Cncurl_setopt_array($curl,%20array(%5Cn%20CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER%20=%3E%201,%5Cn%20CURLOPT_URL%20=%3E%20'https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/recent/created?hapikey=demo',%5Cn%5Cn));%5Cn//%20Send%20the%20request%20%2526%20save%20response%20to%20$resp%5Cn$resp%20=%20curl_exec($curl);%5Cn%5Cnif(!$resp%20%7C%7C%20strlen(trim($resp%20))%20==%200)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20echo%20%22Empty%20Result%22;%5Cn%7D%5Cnelse%7B%5Cnecho%20%22%3Cbr%3EIt's%20not%20empty.%22;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn//print_r($resp);%5Cn//var_export($resp);%5Cn$json%20=%20json_decode($resp,%20true);%5Cn//print_r($json);%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22%3Cbr%3EIn%20the%20Loop%22;%5Cn%5Cnecho%20$json-%3Eresults[0]-%3Eproperties-%3Edealname-%3Evalue;%5Cn%5Cnforeach%20($json-%3Eresults%20as%20$deal)%20%7B%5Cn%20$name%20=%20$deal-%3Eproperties-%3Edealname-%3Evalue;%5Cn%5Cn%20echo%20%22%3Cbr%3E%22.$name;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn//%20Close%20request%20to%20clear%20up%20some%20resources%5Cncurl_close($curl);%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn?%3E)

Comment: 3 loops all do the same thing

Comment: It would be easier if you added the actual JSON string rather than the loaded version.

Comment: @NigelRen I have added the JSON String.

Comment: Please add *full* JSON string

Comment: Done.. @JDev518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON contains a `results` array with a bunch of objects in it. You don't need nested loops. You only need one loop to iterate that results array. To get the value you want from each of the objects, you just have to use the appropriate syntax to access that property nested within it.

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);

foreach ($data->results as $deal) {
    $name = $deal->properties->dealname->value;
}
```

That will get you the dealname value from each of the objects in your data.

If you really just want the first one ("Leaky faucet in LA") then you don't need a loop at all.

```
echo $data->results[0]->properties->dealname->value;
```

Comment: For the Echo Statement, I get an error "Trying to get property of non-object " and for the foreach loop, I get an error saying " type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: Did you `json_decode` the JSON string? I added that to the answer.

Comment: I did. I have edited the Post with the URL to my code

Comment: The problem isn't in this code. It's not getting the JSON from the URL. Test it here with with file_get_contents: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C%3Fphp%0A%0A%24json%20%3D%20file_get_contents('https%3A%2F%2Fapi.hubapi.com%2Fdeals%2Fv1%2Fdeal%2Frecent%2Fcreated%3Fhapikey%3Ddemo')%3B%0A%0A%24data%20%3D%20json_decode(%24json)%3B%0A%0Aforeach%20(%24data-%3Eresults%20as%20%24deal)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%24name%20%3D%20%24deal-%3Eproperties-%3Edealname-%3Evalue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var_dump(%24name)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%3F%3E